# Stripe: Shipping address not submitting via Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm using `Node` and `Express` to submit a form to `Stripe`. When I create the new customer for the charge, I submit the related data with it: https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_customer

Everything appears in Stripe's dashboard just fine except shipping address. I'm not getting any errors in command line or console so it's really hard to trouble shoot. My only guess is that there's some config I need to pass into Stripe that tells them I'm collecting address. No idea.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's what I've got now.

```js
stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.stripeEmail,
    source: req.body.stripeToken,
    description: "this is he",
    metadata: {
      this: "that",
      gender: "female",
      party: "green"
    },
    shipping: {
      name: "Yuki Matthews",
      address: {
        line1: "123 Yukon Ave.",
        line2: "Suite B",
        city: "Seattle",
        state: "Washington",
        country: "United States",
        postal_code: "98144"
      }
    }
    
  })
```

Comment: I dont think there is a name field option in shipping object
https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#charge_object

Comment: Log what the call returns, you should see the full customer object including shipping address if all went well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. The shipping address is not displayed in the dashboard, but can be retrieved when you [retrieve the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_customer) via the API.